# HttpContext.Current is null in Hub OnDisconnected method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, httpcontext

I want create private chat with roles, which use the SignalR technology. For this I used System.Web.Security.Roles mechanism which use HttpContext. When I disconnect from hub i can't get information about role (Roles.GetRolesForUser()). Why? How I can resolve this situation

```
public class MessengerHub : Hub
   {
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current; //<--- not null
        var role = Roles.GetRolesForUser();//<--- returned role
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current; //<--- null!!!!
        var role = Roles.GetRolesForUser();//<--- throwed httpContext not defined
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }
  }
```

Comment: asp.net signalr ? Or asp.net core signalr ?

Comment: hi dear  jason pan,  asp.net mvc